# Firebase not reconnecting after opening flutter app from background

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app that makes use of Firebase as a DB. Everything works fine when the app is in the foreground, however, the Firebase connection stops working if I send the app to background for 1+ hours and open it up again. In this case all read and write operations stop working indefinitely. I know the OS usually kills processes when the app is in background, but assumed that the Firebase SDK would automatically handle the reconnection.

I'm initializing Firebase in my main method as below:

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  await DotEnv().load('.env');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I am performing a simple get operation using Firebase as below:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("endTime").doc("docId").get().then((value){

  setState(() {
    timeToNextMatch = value.data()['timeToNextMatch'];
  });

});
```

These are the errors I see when I open the app from the background :

1. "Socket is not connected"
2. "Could not register as server for FlutterObservatoryPublisher. Check your network settings and relaunch the application."
3. WatchStream (1049e1698) Stream error: 'Unknown: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.'

Should I be reestablishing my Firebase connection or is there any other best practice that I'm missing here? I'm new to Flutter / Firebase so appreciate the help!

1. Tested it with Firebase streams and one time get operations. Issue exists in both cases.
2. Logged the Firebase user instance id which is not null after opening app from background.

I expect the Firebase SDK to take care of this; so wondering if I'm not initializing it correctly?

Comment: Have you checked this [**GitHub issue**](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/6355#issuecomment-859536653) which describes that using `flutter clean` or deleting Gradle cache solves the issue.

Comment: Hi Rohit - This is a case where the Firebase connection stops working completely - the github issue looks like one where there is a long delay for the connection to reestablish. Also, I'm facing this issue on iOS.